# Begining Python os.fork output

Tags: python, fork

I am new to python.

I know that `os.fork` create a copy.

What is the output of this ? And please explain.

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    print(1, end = '')
    print(3, end = '')
else:
    print(3, end = '')
    print(2, end = '')
print(0, end = '')
```

Comment: run it and see output.

Comment: need explain instead of result

Comment: `fork` creates second process. Oryginal (parent) process has `pid == 0` and print `1`, `3` and `0`. New (child) process has `pid != 0` and print `3`, `2` and `0`

Comment: cheers ill try to understand it

Comment: You could start with [`os.fork`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork) from the documentation

Comment: the output could be like: 130 320 or 320 130 or 312 300 or 132 300 right?

Comment: yes, you can get different results - I get `320130` but if you add somewhere `time.sleep` then you can get differen result.

Comment: so all of above are the possible result? any of them impossible?(130 320 or 320 130 or 312 300 or 132 300 ) just wanna make sure I got this question

Comment: theoretically all are possible.

Answer (score 0):

> make two identical copies of address spaces, one for the parent and
>   the other for the child that basically os.fork does

refer [this](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html)